# Date format conversion works on windows but gives an error in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am trying to format date to a specific format. The code deploys successfully on Windows with Python 3.7. however, it doesn't work on Linux Debian 9.11 - Oython 3.5. Cannot figure out the solution. Any help is really appreciated.

```
def parse_date(date_string: str, date_format: str) -> str:
    """
    '2019-04-12T00:00:00.000-07:00' --> "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"
    '2019-04-28T07:25:39.668Z' --> "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
    """
    req_date = dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
    return req_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

**Works on windows**

`parse_date('2019-04-11T00:00:00.000-07:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")`

**Fails on Linux**

`parse_date('2019-04-11T00:00:00.000-07:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")`

> ValueError: time data '2019-04-11T00:00:00.000-07:00' does not match
>   format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

expected return value : `'2019-04-11'`

Comment: What is your version of Python in Linux? there's no %z in strptime for python version 2.7.

Comment: I have updated the information regarding the versions and operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using regex to solve overcome the problem and it works.

```
def parse_date_regex(date_string: str) -> str:
    """
    :return:
    """
    date = re.split('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', date_string)
    return [res for res in date if len(res) == 10][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.5, you could not have a colon in your UTC offset.

> UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the object is naive).

In Python 3.7 that changed to allow the colon.